Calculating absorption coefficient from Transmittance and Reflectance
I have some spectrum data from a sample, specifically the Transmittance and Reflectance of the sample. I would like to use this to calculate the absorption coefficient.
I found a here with an equation for the absorption coefficient
$\alpha = \frac{1}{t}ln((1-R)^2/T)$
Is this correct? I'm not sure where this comes from. In particular I'm not sure why the value is squared. I checked some of the sources but I can't access them all.
Just from my own reasoning, the absorption coefficient is related to the Transmittance through a sample, and would have the form $\alpha \propto ln(1/T) $. And I suppose it makes sense to correct that value for any light that has already been reflected away, $\alpha \propto ln((1-R)/T)$
Which, if any, are correct?

$T$ passed through your sample and $1-R$ goes into it. Assuming these are intensities and an absorption coefficient in units of per unit length and a sample of thickness $t$, then
$$ T = (1-R)\exp(-\alpha t)\ , $$
$$ \alpha = \frac{1}{t}\ln\left( \frac{1-R}{T}\right)\ . $$
However, this simple formula does not properly account for multiple reflections from the top and bottom surfaces. If one does that, and if $\alpha t \gg 1$, then you get the formula in your question
$$ \alpha \simeq \frac{1}{t}\ln\left( \frac{(1-R)^2}{T}\right)\ . $$
See Look & Leach (2016) for a discussion of this and other approximations.

Thank you very much, thank you especially for the link, I think it pretty much what I am looking for

The point is that your sample has two interfaces, so there is not just the reflection loss at the first interface. Furthermore, the equation given in the source is not exact but an approximation, as it ignores the internal reflections in the sample.
Derivation of the full equations
I assume a sample with two parallel surfaces and that the light falls perpendicular to the surface.
(The name $t$ for the thickness is a bit inconvenient as $t$ is typically the time or the transmittance amplitude, I will use $d$ in the remainder of my answer. Further, we assume a thick sample compared to the coherence length of the used light source, so there are no interference effects and intensities just add up).
The reflection coefficient at each of the two surfaces (when entering the sample and when leaving it) is the same according to the Fresnel equations (for an angle of incidence of $\theta = \pi/2$, with the complex indices of refraction $n_1$ of first medium in the direction of the ray and $n_2$ of the second):
$$ R_0 = \left|\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right|^2. $$
This gives the following formula for the total transmittance:
\begin{align*}
 T &= (1-R_0) e^{-\alpha d} (1 - R_0) \\
   &\quad+ (1-R_0) e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} (1-R_0)\\
   &\quad+ (1-R_0) e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} (1-R_0) \\
   &\quad+ \ldots \\
   &= (1-R_0)^2 e^{-\alpha d} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha 2nd} R_0^{2n} \\
   &= (1-R_0)^2 e^{-\alpha d} \frac{1}{1-e^{-2\alpha d} R_0^2}  
\end{align*}
Each term in the sum corresponds to an extra internal reflection roundtrip:

The first multiplier in the first term $(1-R_0)$ is the transmittance of the interface air-sample, then we have the absorption of passing through the thickness of the sample $e^{-\alpha d}$, and then again the transmittance through the sample-air interface $(1-R_0)$.
But this is not the total transmittance yet: the fraction $(1-R_0)e^{-\alpha d}$ of the light intensity reaches the sample-air interface, a fraction $R_0$ of this is reflected by the sample-air interface, absorption does its work in the thickness $e^{-\alpha d}$, then we have a reflection on the front sample-air interface $R_0$, absorption $e^{-\alpha d}$ through the thickness again, and, finally, multiplied by $(1-R_0)$ again a contribution to the total transmittance.
And so on for the higher terms (each internal reflection roundtrip contributes a factor $R_0^2 e^{-2d\alpha}$).

We know $R_0^2 e^{-2d\alpha} < 1$ so we can sum the geometric series.
Following the same recipe, for the total reflectance we get the following formula${}^*$:
\begin{align*}
  R &= R_0  \\
    &\quad+ (1 - R_0) e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} (1-R_0) \\
    &\quad+ (1 - R_0) e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} R_0 e^{-\alpha d} (1-R_0) \\
    &\quad+ ... \\
    &= R_0 + (1 - R_0)^2 e^{-2\alpha d} R_0 \sum_{n=0}^\infty R_0^{2n} e^{-\alpha 2dn} \\
    &= R_0 + (1 - R_0)^2 e^{-2\alpha d} R_0 \frac{1}{1 - R_0^2 e^{-2\alpha d}}
\end{align*}
From those two formulae you can exactly compute $R_0$ and $\alpha$ from the measured total transmission $T$ and reflectance $R$ (at least numerically, I believe there's no elementary analytical solution).
Obtaining the approximation
Under the assumption that $e^{-\alpha d}$ is sufficiently small you can drop all the higher order terms due to multiple reflections, then the system of equations reduces to:
\begin{align*}
  T &= (1-R_0) e^{-\alpha d} (1-R_0) \\ 
  R &= R_0 
\end{align*}
This system of equations can straighforwardly solved for $\alpha$ to give the result form your source (which a an approximation that holds in a certain limit):
\begin{align*}
 \alpha = \frac 1 d \ln\left(\frac{(1-R)^2}{T} \right)
\end{align*}

${}^*$ Of course, $T + R = 1$ does not hold for the sample as there is absorption in the sample! It only holds over a single interface or if there's no absorption.

Excellent, thank you very much for the derivation. I can see where the term comes from now and where I was mistaken
